# Slow rendering SVG animation on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, snap.svg

Hellou guys. In this example i have an SVG animation which simulates turn the sheet of the book.

In mozilla its work fine, but in Chrome and Opera its work horrible.

Can you helpme optimize this animation for Chrome?

[EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LONQaq)

> .js Used on EXAMPLE link:

**snap.svg-min.js**

**classie.js**

```
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

**svgLoader.js**

```
    ;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function SVGLoader( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    SVGLoader.prototype.options = {
        speedIn : 500,
        easingIn : mina.linear
    }

    SVGLoader.prototype._init = function() {
        var s = Snap( this.el.querySelector( 'svg' ) );
        this.path = s.select( 'path' );
        this.initialPath = this.path.attr('d');

        var openingStepsStr = this.el.getAttribute( 'data-opening' );
        this.openingSteps = openingStepsStr ? openingStepsStr.split(';') : '';
        this.openingStepsTotal = openingStepsStr ? this.openingSteps.length : 0;
        if( this.openingStepsTotal === 0 ) return;

        // if data-closing is not defined then the path will animate to its original shape
        var closingStepsStr = this.el.getAttribute( 'data-closing' ) ? this.el.getAttribute( 'data-closing' ) : this.initialPath;
        this.closingSteps = closingStepsStr ? closingStepsStr.split(';') : '';
        this.closingStepsTotal = closingStepsStr ? this.closingSteps.length : 0;

        this.isAnimating = false;

        if( !this.options.speedOut ) {
            this.options.speedOut = this.options.speedIn;
        }
        if( !this.options.easingOut ) {
            this.options.easingOut = this.options.easingIn;
        }
    }

    SVGLoader.prototype.show = function() {
        if( this.isAnimating ) return false;
        this.isAnimating = true;
        // animate svg
        var self = this,
            onEndAnimation = function() {
                classie.addClass( self.el, 'pageload-loading' );
            };
        this._animateSVG( 'in', onEndAnimation );
        classie.add( this.el, 'show' );
    }

    SVGLoader.prototype.hide = function() {
        var self = this;
        classie.removeClass( this.el, 'pageload-loading' );
        this._animateSVG( 'out', function() { 
            // reset path
            self.path.attr( 'd', self.initialPath );
            classie.removeClass( self.el, 'show' );
            self.isAnimating = false; 
        } );
    }

    SVGLoader.prototype._animateSVG = function( dir, callback ) {
        var self = this,
            pos = 0,
            steps = dir === 'out' ? this.closingSteps : this.openingSteps,
            stepsTotal = dir === 'out' ? this.closingStepsTotal : this.openingStepsTotal,
            speed = dir === 'out' ? self.options.speedOut : self.options.speedIn,
            easing = dir === 'out' ? self.options.easingOut : self.options.easingIn,
            nextStep = function( pos ) {
                if( pos > stepsTotal - 1 ) {
                    if( callback && typeof callback == 'function' ) {
                        callback();
                    }
                    return;
                }
                self.path.animate( { 'path' : steps[pos] }, speed, easing, function() { nextStep(pos); } );
                pos++;
            };

        nextStep(pos);
    }

    // add to global namespace
    window.SVGLoader = SVGLoader;

})( window );
```

**and this scrypt on html file:**

```
(function() {
            var pageWrap = document.getElementById( 'pagewrap' ),
                pages = [].slice.call( pageWrap.querySelectorAll( 'div.container' ) ),
                currentPage = 0,
                triggerLoading = [].slice.call( pageWrap.querySelectorAll( 'a.pageload-link' ) ),
                loader = new SVGLoader( document.getElementById( 'loader' ), { speedIn : 400, easingIn : mina.easeinout } );

            function init() {
                triggerLoading.forEach( function( trigger ) {
                    trigger.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                        loader.show();
                        // after some time hide loader
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            loader.hide();

                            classie.removeClass( pages[ currentPage ], 'show' );
                            // update..
                            currentPage = currentPage ? 0 : 1;
                            classie.addClass( pages[ currentPage ], 'show' );

                        }, 2000 );
                    } );
                } );    
            }

            init();
        })();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and show js code here. What is your code, and what is library code? Please list the libraries used.

Comment: So why did you now remove the html and css code from your question? Instead of posting library code, it would have sufficed to say that you are using the technology stack described in [this article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/23/page-loading-effects/) and listed in  [this project](https://github.com/codrops/PageLoadingEffects)

Comment: you have all the code on codepen EXAMPLE on my post. Try it on Chrome and you will see that it work slowly